# Loopback inq operator not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, pagination, loopbackjs

This is my code:

I have a model named **Feeds**. The array **groupIds** contains the groups of a user. I'm using the loopback-ds-paginate-mixin
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-ds-paginate-mixin) for paginating results.

```
    var filter = {
        limit : req.query.limit,
        skip : req.query.skip,
        order: 'created DESC'
    };
    if(groupIds){
      filter.where = {or :[{share:"public"}, {and :[{share:"group"}, { groupId:{inq: groupIds}}]}]}
    }else{
      filter.where = {share:"public"}
    }
    Feeds.paginate(filter).then(function(allFeeds) {
      res.status(200).json(allFeeds.items);
    }).catch(function(err){
      //Error
    });
```